# How to sandbox JVM on a CentOS

Tags: security, chroot, docker, sandbox

I'm looking for the best way to sandbox a JVM process running on CentOS. The process must not be allowed to spawn subprocesses, call ptrace or kill, write access should be limited only to specific temporary directories, and I'd like to restrict IP addresses the process can connect to. On a side note, I know that Java offers its own security manager mechanism, but I'm looking for an OS-level solution.

Does Docker tick all these requirements?